# Django: Counting objects based on filter value that changes?

Tags: python, django, database-design, model, count

I have the following models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    detail = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class PossibleAnswers(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Each `Question` has `PossibleAnswers` defined defined by the User. For Example: Question - What is the best fruit? Possible Answers - Apple, Orange, Grapes. Now other user's can `Answer` the question with their responses restricted to `PossibleAnswers`.

The problem I'm having is getting a count of each `Answer`. How many people responded by selecting Apple vs Orange vs Grapes?

`Question.answer_set.filter(value="Grapes").count()` returns a count of all grape answers, but what if you don't know what the filter criteria (grapes in this case) will be? Since the user defines the answer options, and defines how many different options there are, how would you get a response count for each answer option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would change your models. Your schema is not normalized. That means you keep the same information (the text of an answer) in multiple places. That is considered a bad thing by itself, but also makes designing the right query much harder. That is how I think your models should look like:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    detail = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class PossibleAnswer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Answer(models.Model):
    possible_answer = models.ForeignKey(PossibleAnswers)
```

Every time a user vote for a possible answer you add a new `Answer` model referencing that possible answer. You can also add additional fields to the `Answer` model, like a Foreign Key referencing the user voting.

Then you would use the following code to get the information (i.e. how many actual answers there are for every possible answer) for a question `foo`:

```
PossibleAnswer.objects.filter(question=foo).annotate(Count('answer'))
```

Comment: +1 This is really good. However wouldn't it be better and clearer to name the models Question, Answer (instead of PossibleAnswer) and Amount or Select or something (instead of Answer)? I mean in this schema the Answer model is functioning like a Vote or a Like models, as it is just used for counting

Comment: Not really, model names should be singular nouns describing a single object, so I wouldn't consider "Count" or "Select" a good name for the model. But you are right this wouldn't be a best solution if we were sure the `Answer` model were just use for counting. In such case I would get rid of the `Answer` model all together, and add a `count` field to the `PossibleAnswer` model instead (which then indeed should be renamed to `Answer`). The field should be then incremented every time a user choose the answer.

Comment: I didn't choose that solution however, because I think it's very likely there are other pieces of information that should be recorded every time user votes, like time, user name or user ip.

Comment: Yeah "Count" or "Select" are not good, I just couldn't really come up with something, but the point is the names as they are now are confusing, and do not express very well the essence of the data they are recording

Comment: Do you think "Question", "Answer" and "Vote" would be better?

Comment: Yes. It isn't exactly a vote but I really can't think of anything better than that (Attempt maybe? Maybe Guess! Guess is good, no?)

Comment: Answer also has an optional "explain" field. That's why I separated it instead of just having Question and Answer. I thought this was the best way to setup the DB.

Comment: Why would you remove Question FK from Answer? What if I wanted to count all answers posted to a related question?

Comment: @thedeepfield An `Answer` is already connected to a `Question` through `PossibleAnswer`. You don't have to, and in fact should not, make a second connection and double the information. In fact the the query in my post already counts answers to a given question.

Comment: Yes the answer provides Grapes: 10 votes, Oranges: 1 vote etc, but what If I want a total vote count for all answers? (Question - 11 votes)

Comment: Good question. The answer is: `Answer.objects.filter(possible_answer__question=foo).count()`

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you out?

```
q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
[{v: q.answer_set.filter(value=v).count()} 
           for v in [pa.value for 
                       pa in q.possibleanswers_set.all()]]
```

It will return a dictionary of {'possible_answer': 'count'} for each possible answer that exists for Question object q.

This is however not the most efficient way of doing things if you intend to use it on a larger scale (say for *all* Question objects), in which case you'd be much better off using aggregation (read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)).

Comment: Though functional, this could have a considerable overhead on the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need an [aggregation query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset):

```
from django.db.models import Count
Question.objects.annotate(Count('answer'))
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just count **all** the answers for every question, instead of giving a different number for every possible answer?